# Oracle SQL not bringing back duplicates to an Oracle Form 10g

Tags: sql, forms, plsql, oracle11g, duplicates

I've created an Oracle SQL query which links to about five tables I'm using in an Oracle FROM clause to an Oracle Form but the problem with the query is that some records are duplicated, so I only want to show one line in the form and not any duplicate records. I've tried GROUP BY and PARTITION BY statements but the query becomes to slow with adding this into the statement.

I'm now thinking of doing this as a procedure and bring back just one of the duplicates if any occur. Would it be best to bring back an ORACLE table of records from the database into the form? How would it be best to look for a duplicate in an Oracle PL/SQL loop?

I've updated the question and adde the full query below to explain it better. The surr_id the first column in select statement below is unique but what I want to show in the Oracle form is the production number along with the other columns which are not unique. There can be duplicates of production number and even sometimes three production number records the same. Hope this helps. I was thinking of putting this in a loop and just grabbing the first production number and then only bringing back each record when the production number changes.

```
select x.surr_id , 
   x.supplier_name as supplier , 
   x.broadcaster_name as broadcaster , 
   ptle.title as production_title , 
   x.production_number as production_number , 
   stle.title as series_title , 
   x.production_source as supplied_source_ind , 
   x.third_party_group_id , 
   x.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id , 
   x.station_id from (select usage_headers.surr_id as surr_id , 
                             broad_supp.supplier_name as supplier_name , 
                             broad_supp.broadcaster_name as broadcaster_name , 
                             usage_headers.production_number as production_number , 
                             productions.production_source as production_source , 
                             broad_supp.station_id as station_id , 
                             usage_headers.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id as prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id ,
                             usage_headers.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id as bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id , 
                             productions.cre_surr_id as cre_surr_id , 
                             productions.prod_series_cre_surr_id as prod_series_cre_surr_id , 
                             broad_supp.third_party_group_id as third_party_group_id 
                      from usage_headers, productions, (SELECT /*+ index (bro bro_pk) */ 
                                                              third_party.surr_id AS THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID, 
                                                              third_party.supplier_group_id AS THIRD_PARTY_GROUP_ID, 
                                                              third_party.dn_root_tp_surr_id AS THIRD_PARTY_ROOT_ID, 
                                                              third_party.supplier_name, bro.station_id AS STATION_ID, 
                                                              bro.dn_tp_name AS BROADCASTER_NAME FROM ( SELECT tp.surr_id, 
                                                                                                               tp.name AS supplier_name, 
                                                                                                               tp.tp_surr_id AS supplier_group_id, 
                                                                                                               tp.dn_root_tp_surr_id FROM third_parties tp 
                                                                                                               CONNECT BY PRIOR tp.surr_id = tp.tp_surr_id 
                                                                                                               START WITH tp.surr_id IN (4251, 4247, 4237, 4034, 10157, 14362, 9834)) third_party 
                      JOIN broadcasters bro ON (third_party.surr_id = bro.tp_surr_id)) broad_supp 
                   where broad_supp.THIRD_PARTY_SURR_ID = usage_headers.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id 
                   AND usage_headers.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id = productions.cre_surr_id 
                   and usage_headers.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id IS NOT NULL 
                   and usage_headers.right_type in ('M','B') 
                   AND usage_headers.udg_surr_id IS NOT NULL 
                   AND NVL(usage_headers.dn_uls_usage_status,'3') NOT IN ('9', '11') 
                   AND productions.production_source <> 'AP') x 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN titles ptle ON ( ptle.cre_surr_id = x.cre_surr_id AND ptle.tt_code = 'R') 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN titles stle ON ( stle.cre_surr_id = x.prod_series_cre_surr_id AND stle.tt_code = 'R')
```

thanks Guys in Advance

Comment: If the entire result set row is duplicated you can use `distinct`, but that might suggest a problem with your query or your data... If some columns are duplicated but others are unique you'd need to decide which to keep, and then possibly aggregate; but you seem to have tried that already. Grouping shouldn't slow it down much, unless you are currently only fetching the first set of rows.

Comment: You need to fix the query, not the user interface.

Comment: Hi Guys, the data in the query is unique but what I want to bring back into the form is not, so the select unique_id, prododuction, station in the query but in form I want to show just the production and station but the production and station sometimes duplicate.

Comment: So why are you including columns in the select list that you won't use? If you don't need them, maybe you don't need all the joins, and won't then get duplicates. It's too vague to tell though really.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting records that are entirely duplicated then just adding a `DISTINCT` clause, so your SELECT becomes `SELECT DISTINCT` will ensure that only one of the records is returned. If even one column is different though then this won't work.

Comment: Distinct adds to the cost of the statement and this DISTINCT slows the query down as it has to do a full scan of the table to get all distinct values.

Comment: In this case then we'd need to see the full statement, so that we can prevent the duplicates from happening at an earlier point.

Comment: @ShaunKinnair - adding `distinct` doesn't force a full table scan, but it does add a sort/prune operation; I'd be surprised if it's noticeably slower though, if you're already ordering the results. If you aren't then it would be a bit slower maybe, but still seems more likely that you're currently only fetching the first set of rows.